# Performance issues : UIView coregraphics drawing inside a Customcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics, custom-cell

I am implementing a UItableView with custom cells.
My custom cell has a UIView inside of it.

I am trying to draw extensive CoreGraphics shapes with gradients in the UIView and I am running into scrolling performance problems -- since the customcell's UIView is getting drawn upon everytime the cell gets displayed.

Are there ways where I could do this differently (such as say, some kind of lazy drawing, drawing asynchronously, UIView caching, preventing the cell from redrawing etc) so as to improve performance?

Deeply appreciate any help, inputs, insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is not to compute your graphics every time at draw time, but to render it offscreen in a UIImageView. Then your cell only has to blit the image, which is as fast as can be.

You can still compute your images lazily and asynchronously. The structure of your code could be similar to the Apple sample code LazyTableImages. Google for it. In that sample code, what's slow is not the drawing time, but the network loading time, but that difference is not significant.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help, I am trying to take the lazy loading route, and have set up my delegate structure. But I am running into problems while trying to do the drawing via the delegate method. The [setNeedsDisplay] method is somehow not firing from my triggering method.(Also this is the first time I am trying to draw off screen, so havent wrapped my head around it yet.). So would appreciate any suggestions/pointers/gotchas in this regard. Thanks again for your help.